# center vertically div inside bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would center a div inside another div vertically.

I have tried using table cell as mentioned in some answers in the site but that does not work I always get the div in top

**CSS**

```
.height1 {
  height:60px;
  line-height:60px
}
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;

}
.indicator {
  width :20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: black;
  vertical-align: middle
}
.badge {
  display:inline-block;
}
.parent {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 height1"> TEXTE</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 parent">
          <div class="badge indicator">testing</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a [demo](https://codepen.io/infofou/pen/BPvjWq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the updated snippet below.

```css
.height1, .parent {
  line-height:60px
}
.row {
  border: 1px solid black;

}
.indicator {
  height:20px;
  background-color: black;
  vertical-align: middle
}
.badge {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 height1"> TEXTE</div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 parent">
          <div class="badge indicator">testing</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

By using the following method you can get that approach. And it will be better solution to maintain the div's.

```
.parent {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```